# Example of nilpotent matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find a nilpotent matrix $ C \in \mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ such that $C \not   =0, C ^2 \not   =0$. The only thing I've accomplished so far is finding a $C$ with $C^2 =0$ which obiously won't do. My idea is that $C$ should be chosen in such a way that by iteratively applying matrix multiplication it's elements  decrease (or increase) in such a way that for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the $n$th iteration yields the zero matrix. But how can this be done? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the Jordan normal form?

Comment: No, I don't....

Comment: Then let me give you a hint: Look only for upper triangular matrices and restrict the entries to elements of $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice construction (that can be easily generalized to arbitrary $n$) and implements your intuition is to consider the operation of the derivative on polynomials. By applying the derivative to polynomials, the degree decreases until it reaches zero.

More explicitly, consider the operator $T \colon \mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[x]$ on the vector space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ given by the derivative $T(p) = p'$. The space $\mathbb{R}_{\leq n}[x]$ is a vector space of dimension $n + 1$ with basis $\mathcal{B} = (1,x,\dots,x^n)$ with $T^{n+1} = 0$ (taking $n + 1$ derivatives of a polynomial of degree $n$ kills it) but $T^n \neq 0$ (as $T^n(x^n) = n!$). By considering the matrix representing $T$, you get your example.

For $n = 2$, we get

$$ [T]_{\mathcal{B}} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot!